# creating buttons dynamically from observable collection

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have an observable collection OBSCollection which i am parsing. In this collection i am checking if the name property is "critical" and if it is "critical" , then i am trying to create red buttons dynamically for each occurence of property.

```
if (OBSCollection.Any(p => p.Name == "Critical"))
                    {

                        criticalcount = OBSCollection.Where(x => x.Name == "Critical").ToList().Count;

                        for (int i = 0; i < criticalcount; i++)
                        {
                            Button temp = new Button();
                            temp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
                            temp.Width = 200;
                            temp.Height = 100;
                            temp.Content = "Critical";
                            CriticalPanel.Children.Add(temp);
                            temp.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(bTapped_Tapped);
                        } 
private void bTapped_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var toremovecritical = OBSCOllection.Where(x => x.Name == "critical").First();
            uiElements.Remove(toremovecritical);
        }
```

Now the above code works only if there is one occurrence of "Critical" property. How can i rewrite the code to work for multiple occurrences and hence create multiple buttons?

Also after displaying the buttons , if  a user clicks on a button the buttons visible property should be collapsed and that particular item should be removed from observable collection. I am able to remove the button from observable collection but i cannot set the visibility property of button to false from bTapped_Tapped handler. Is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: doesn't answer your direct question, but IMHO this screams for a data template (on your ListView or GridView) that includes the button and sets the visibility to Visible when the value of the Name is "Critical" (via a Converter in the binding).  By doing so you eliminate all of the code (with exception of button tap handling) and retain separation of concerns between your View (Button) and your ViewModel (OBSCollection)

Comment: If you put a break point in the for iteration, do you have a critical count higher thant 1 ?
Also, if you put a break point after the for iteration, if you check CriticalPanel.Children, do you have more than 1 child ?

Comment: @Oliver right now , i know i have only one child so the code works. My issue is if there is more than 1 "critical" , then my code will try to create multiple buttons with same name which will throw up an error.

Comment: Then, either don't give a name to the button if it is not necessary or give it a name like : "buttonName" + i , this way you will have buttonName1, buttonName2, etc.. and your names will remain unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a REALLY basic example using MVVM.

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red" Content="{Binding Name}" Click="CriticalClick" DataContext="{Binding}"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>

</Grid>
```

ViewModel & Model:

```
public class ThingViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things { get; set; }

    public ThingViewModel()
    {
        var allThings = new List<Thing>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                allThings.Add(new Thing { Name = "Critical" });
            else
                allThings.Add(new Thing { Name = "`NonCritical" });
        }

        this.Things = new ObservableCollection<Thing>(allThings.Where(x => x.Name == "Critical"));
    }
}

  public class Thing
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Code Behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new ThingViewModel();
    }

    private void CriticalClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tappedThing = (Thing) ((Button) sender).DataContext;

        ((ThingViewModel) this.DataContext).Things.Remove(tappedThing);
    }
```

This is a really simple example of how to do it with binding and MVVM. It gives you a starting point for what you are asking for though.

Hope it helps.